# Active Record results to be ordered in specific way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Job table with column `job_type`, `job_type` can be either `top`, `hot` or `normal`. Now when I list all jobs I want `top` jobs to be shown first, followed by `hot` jobs and at last `normal` jobs. I would also like to sort the jobs in descending order`(created_at: :desc)`. I have following scopes

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  scope :hot_jobs, -> { where(job_type: 'hot') }
  scope :top_jobs, -> { where(job_type: 'top') }
  scope :normal_jobs, -> { where(job_type: 'normal') }
end
```

**What I tried.**

In controller I tried something like this

```
@jobs = Job.hot_jobs.order(created_at: :desc).or(Job.top_jobs.order(created_at: :desc)).or(Job.normal_jobs.order(created_at: :desc))
```

but the above code is not working. Above code result is same as `Job.all.order(created_at: :desc)`

So how can I list jobs in following order `Top Jobs` followed by `Hot Jobs` followed by `Normal Jobs`. I can do some hack if I use array but I don't want to convert `ActiveRecord#Relations` to Array because that will create problem with `will_paginate` and I can't use `includes` to prevent `N + 1` query

I am using Rails 6.0.4.1

**Update**

I changed `job_type` column to `integer` and not I am able to do

```
@jobs = Job.active.order(job_type: :asc, created_at: :desc).limit(48)
```

this solved by problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a case statement in your order.

The trick in Rails 6 is to wrap it in Arel.sql, or you get a "non-attribute argument" error

```
@jobs = Job.all.order(
        Arel.sql(
          "case when job_type = 'top' then 1 
           when job_type = 'hot' then 2
           else 3 end asc"), created_at: :desc)
```

if you have a default order scope on job, just change `order` to `reorder`

Comment: thanks it worked. It also worked without using `Arel.sql`